# Как записать данные от клиента в DBGrid?

Tags: dbgrid, delphi, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте) В продолжение темы "Клиент - сервер - офис" столкнулся с проблемой записи данных а DBGrid... 
К примеру на сервер приходит сообщение:

```
s:=socket.ReceiveText;
  Split('&',s,OutPutList);
if(outputlist.Strings[0] = 'db') then
   begin
    //запись данных в DBGrid
   end;
```

(кстати решена проблема "разнородности" данных;))
Далее нужно остальные значения Outputlist Заносить в DBGrid, причем получается что первые 8 (1-8) outputlist.strings[] должны заносится в первую строку, далее во вторую и т.д до конца outputlist...  И еще был бы оч благодарен, если подсказали как реализовать вычисления в DBGrid... к примеру значение9 (ячейка DBgrid каждой строки) получается как значение3*значение4 (записанные ранее данные), и так для каждой строки, на этапе получения сообщения db от клиента... Рыскал по Инету, но ничего подобного и понятного не нашел... Спасибо)

Comment: Это плохое решение проблемы разнородности. Очень ненадёжное.

Comment: Таблица не обязана уметь делать подобные вещи. Таблица - это компонент представления. Никакой логики она обрабатывать по определению не должна. Поэтому, ваши поиски были обречены на провал. Единственное, что вы могли бы обнаружить, это встраивание эксела как COM-объекта. Но это неважное решение.

Comment: Для того чтобы реализовать вычисления, необходимо иметь хоть какую-то модель данных в вашем приложении и нужен контроллер, который бы вставлял эти "чистые" данные в таблицу попутно вычисляю вычисляемые ячейки таблицы.

Comment: Это называется MVC. Примеров - море разливанное :)

Comment: @cy6erGn0m, а что скажите про запросы?... (вопрос отредактирован)

Comment: Честно говоря, я не понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Что значит выделить значение? Если вы хотите отобрать только один столбец, то и пишите имя столбца вместо звёздочки: SELECT field1 FROM table1 WHERE field1=value1

Comment: Про ADOQuary - это вообще непонятно. Если вы хотите таким способом запихать данные в DbGrid, то это вообще феерический бред и редкостная жесть. Нельзя использовать что-либо не по назначению. Это всегда чревато. Зачем вам вообще DbGrid? И почему нельзя использовать StringGrid, как предлагал winrarhero я не пойму никак

Comment: @cy6erGn0m как я уже объяснял winrarhero - от клиента приходит сообщение socket.ReceiveText, там содержаться инф о заказе т.е. примерно 2-3 строки по 8-9 записей..Эти данные нужно сразу же внести в БД, попутно вычисляя некоторые значения, которые также будут записаны в БД.. Если только вы имеете в виду то что, при запуске отправляется запрос в БД на вывод всех ранее введенных данных в StringGrid, затем когда приходит сообщение, эти данные заносятся в StringGrid, производятся вычисления, результаты также записываются, а затем на выходе из программы посылается запрос на обновление БД..Так?..

Comment: Аа.. теперь я понял. Тогда вам надо при получении данных действительно выполнить вставку в базу вычисляя необходимые данных. А DbGrid надо просто обновить.. пуская грида просто отображает результат какого-нибудь SELECT'а. Возможно, это не супер-эффективно, но зато просто. Если очень уж хочется супер-эффективности, то тогда придётся тянуть всё это через StringGrid примерно так, как вы описали.

Comment: Т.е возможны два варианта - через запросы добавлять, принятые данные, сразу в DBGrid, или же через StringGrid, запросом вносить сюда данные из БД, и потом, после некоторых действий,  запросом "новые" из StringGrid  записывать в БД... С чем могут возникнуть сложности?..

Comment: С тем, что вы всё делаете в одном огромном методе, котоый и с сокетом работает, и с таблицей.. а потом ещё и SQL туда же..

Comment: А как работаешь Split? Вы ведь его небось через TStringList реализовали?

Comment: Новый вопрос создам...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запись данных в DBGrid, вернее AdoTable...

```
while k<outputlist.Count-1 do
    begin
    Adotable1.Insert;
     ADOtable1.FieldByName('nameSt').AsString:= outputlist.Strings[k];
     ...//так далее для всех столбцов
    k:=k+n  //n - число столбцов
     dbgrid1.Update;
    end;
```

Все данные в DBGrid!... а на выходе из приложения:

```
if DBGrid1.EditorMode or DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Modified then DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Post;
```

и получается что данные сохранены в БД...

Для "вытаскивания" нужных данных из таблицы БД, кидаем на форму ADOQuery, подсоединяем его к БД, и через него, по SQL-запросу вытаскиваем нужные данные и записываем куда хотим...

К примеру:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT SUM(name1) FROM tab1');
ADOQuery1.Active:=True;
Label2.Caption:=AdoQuery1.Fields[0].AsString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример работы со StrigGrid совсем короткий:

```
StringGrid1.RowsCount := 100;
StringGrid1.ColCount := 10;
StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1] := 'Первая ячейка';
StringGrid1.Cells[2, 1] := 'другая ячейка';
StringGrid1.Cells[9, 9] := 'ещё какая-то';
```

Про вставку в базу

```
ADOCommand1.CommandText := 'INSERT INTO mytable (mycolumn) VALUES (:value1)';
ADOCommand1.Parameters.ParamByName('value1').value = 'myvalue';
ADOCommand1.Execute;
```

Answer (score 0):

DBGrid это компонент, предназначенный манипулировать данными из dataSource. В вашем случае лучше StringGrid использовать.

Comment: StringGrid не может работать с данными, БД... А нужно как раз это...

Comment: Если нужно отобразить данные из БД, преобразовав их (сгруппировать, произвести вычисления и т.п.) то я бы результаты запроса сохранил в массив, сделал бы то, что требуется и вывел бы массив в StringGrid. Это очень глупо? серьезно спрашиваю, ибо такое у меня есть в работающем приложении.

Comment: Дело в том что, от клиента приходит сообщение socket.ReceiveText, там содержаться инф о заказе т.е. примерно 2-3 строки по 8-9 записей.. Эти данные нужно сразу же внести в БД, попутно вычисляя некоторые значения, которые также будут записаны в БД.. и сохраняться.. Если только вы имеете в виду то что, при запуске отправляется запрос в БД на вывод всех ранее введенных данных в StringGrid, затем когда приходит сообщение, эти данные заносятся в StrihgGrid, производятся вычисления, результаты также записываются, а затем на выходе из программы посылается запрос на обновление БД... Так?...

Comment: Оу, я затупил видимо, думал вам просто надо данные, полученные из БД просто отобразить.

Comment: Ничего страшного.. Данные и так отображаются в DBGrid...

Comment: Может все же так сделать: вывести данные в StringGrid, преобразовать эти данные как вам нужно, дать пользователю эти данные отредактировать, потом SQL запросом записать все изменения в базу?